# Data Access Provisioning in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, authorization, wso2-api-manager, restful-authentication, wso2-identity-server

Using scope functionality in WSO2 API Manager, I am able to limit access to my back-end APIs like  http://mydomain/context/students(GET - list of all students),http://mydomain/context/student/S101 (GET - details of student S101) or  http://mydomain/context/student/create (POST) only to users who are assigned specific roles. That much fine-grained control, I am able to implement.

But I want to implement more detailed filtering : User U101 is allowed to view details of  students S101 to S110 only. So http://mydomain/context/student/S111 should be blocked for him and http://mydomain/context/students should only return details of S101 to S110. Can I implement this filtering in WSO2 API manager?
(I have an RDBMS table (part of back-end, not in WSO2) with the mapping of users to the list of students, whose details the user is allowed to access.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API Manager, any modification to the response content are done via mediation scripts. In you scenario, the role - content mapping should be stored in API Manager in order to filter the content. For this you can use a class mediator to filter the respose content.

In the mediator you have to get the role - content mapping. You can either define it in the class itself or retrieve it from your database.

Please follow documentation[1] and [2] for how to write a class mediator and how to use it.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Class+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.
One doubt, you said  "In you scenario, the role - content mapping should be stored in API Manager in order to filter the content" in first para and then " You can either define it in the class itself or retrieve it from your database." in second para. ---- I am a bit confused here.
Should I store the mapping in API manager ? Will it make my filtering configuration easier compared to storing it in a  DB, not part of API Manager?

Comment: I’m very sorry for the confusion. Let me make it clear. You can store it as apim registry resource (in api manager), hardcode in your class mediator or store in your db. In the class mediator you can implement the retrieval method based on that. IMO, as you already have the mapping in your db, the best way is to call your db from the class mediator. So you do not want to replicate it.

Comment: ok.thanks again...I will try implementing the way you suggested.
btw, can you suggest if the feature I am looking for is more easily implementable in any other WSO2 product, which I can use instead of  apim? (For example, AFIK, WSO2 IS can also be used for api authentication and authorization. Does it support such a feature out-of the-box?)